# How to bake one texture for one mesh with multiple textures blender 2.8

Tags: texture-baking

I'm trying to perform material merging into one texture in accordance with the solutions:

**[Baking two textures into one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40995/baking-two-textures-into-one)**
and
**[Baking multiple materials into one texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91526/baking-multiple-materials-into-one-texture)**

But due to differences in **Blender 2.8** interface I can't find 'bake' option in Render menu. And 'Texture atlas' wasn't found.

Could you kindly provide some steps to perform this task?

Thanks,
...I feel that it should be simple but hours spent and I was not lucky in this...

Answer (score 2):

**Due to changes in Blender 2.80, the Texture Atlas add-on might have become obsolete.**

In Blender 2.7x it was only possible to edit one object at a time, thus you were only able to see one UV layout at a time. 
In Blender 2.80 it is possible to edit two or more objects at the same time.

Start with UV-unwrapping the individual objects, just don't move or place the UV islands to minimize texture space.

[image: Unwrap individual objects]

When both objects are unwrapped, select both objects, go into edit mode, move your mouse to the UV Editor, select everything and go to "UV - Pack Islands".

[image: Pack UV Islands]

Now every UV island from every object should have its own UV Space and also roughly the same texel density.

[image: Individual Texture Spaces]

You can now either modify the UV layouts further (optimizing texture space, sorting UVs, etc.) or you can continue to bake your materials.

As for now (Blender 2.80 Beta), baking textures only works in Cycles. Go to "Properties - Render - Render Engine" and switch to Cycles.

[image: switch from Eevee to Cycles]

Comment: Nice tricks, @metaphor_set! Thanks
But I've met a problem while performing your steps
I have a model with several materials and textures

[![Several materials][1]][1]

Thus I have had this picture before your steps

[![Before bake][2][2]

And after unwrap all selected and so on I got this


[![After bake][3]][3]

Could you tell me the steps I made wrong? 

[1]: https://imgur.com/D23TnZz
[2]: https://imgur.com/0JwODZ1
[3]: https://imgur.com/6oQiyk4

Comment: You destroyed your UV layouts. Solution: Create a copy of your model (same blend file, different collection). Unwrap that copy like above. Then bake the original textures to a new texture for your new model.

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean "different collection"? I make File-Save a Copy or File-Save as.... Blender saves .blend file but images is still being unmerged.

Comment: A copy of your model -> Shift-D. Also, please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rYaBDcHG6U) if you want to know more about collections and how to use them.