# Understanding texture margin in baking

Tags: texturing

I know for what texture margin is using (http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding). Sowhy we cant just set margin to infininty? Margins do not overlap each other, what's the difference. Why there is margin limit to 64 px? This question just "does not give me the rest".
[image]

Comment: If you want a bake margin more than 64pixels then just type in a larger number.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog ok, thank you. Now I need to recognize why I cant just type "infinity", why there is no this button. Because, how I understand, more margin - more good, so Idont understand why people choose low numbers

Comment: Salt is a good flavor enhancer, more salt gives you more flavor. But too much salt and you get just a harsh salty taste and you kill your internal organs. Margins are good to prevent  some artifacts. Too much margins and each island will "bleed" onto each other making a huge mess. I recently wrote a bit about margins [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269801/53447) if you like some reading.